# What is the difference between sysupgrade.tar and factory.img when installing the LEDE Project?

Tags: linux, lede

Trying to download a firmware from my Netgear, I see options from

- `R7800-squashfs-sysupgrade.tar`
- `R7800-squashfs-factory.img`

What is the difference between the `sysupgrade.tar` and `factory.img`?

Answer (score 3):

From [this forum post](https://www.gargoyle-router.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1412) by the moderator DoesItMatter,

> **sysupgrade.bin** is for any router that is currently running either
>   openwrt or gargoyle and can be flashed via the GUI.
>
> **factory.bin** files are meant to be flashed over factory stock
>   firmware routers - they usually have some extra "magic bytes"
>   i.e. a trick header - to fool the factory firmware into thinking its
>   reading its own factory firmware, not 3rd party firmware.

The [docs affirm this,](https://lede-project.org/docs/guide-quick-start/standardflashinginstructions)

- If your device is running the firmware it came with (often called “stock”, “factory”, or “vendor” firmware) download the file for a **“factory installation”** from Device Page or Device Tech data
- If your device is already running LEDE (or OpenWrt) download the file for a **“sysupgrade installation”** from Device Page or Device Techdata